How to make the following GET request using boost
I have a get request in C#, I need to convert it to C++ (boost)
get request in C#:
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

class Program
{
    private static readonly string key = "<your-translator-key>";
    private static readonly string endpoint = "https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com";

    // location, also known as region.
    // required if you're using a multi-service or regional (not global) resource. It can be found in the Azure portal on the Keys and Endpoint page.
    private static readonly string location = "<YOUR-RESOURCE-LOCATION>";

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Input and output languages are defined as parameters.
        string route = "/translate?api-version=3.0&from=en&to=fr&to=zu";
        string textToTranslate = "I would really like to drive your car around the block a few times!";
        object[] body = new object[] { new { Text = textToTranslate } };
        var requestBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body);

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage())
        {
            // Build the request.
            request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
            request.RequestUri = new Uri(endpoint + route);
            request.Content = new StringContent(requestBody, Encoding.UTF8 "application/json");
            request.Headers.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", key);
            // location required if you're using a multi-service or regional (not global) resource.
            request.Headers.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region", location);

            // Send the request and get response.
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
            // Read response as a string.
            string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}

get request in boost:https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/quick_start.html
due to the huge amount of additional input data, it is not clear how to use them

I think your question is how to write a C++ webserver. Yet you only show irrelevant C# code. (the only thing that matters is what your http request will look like). Asking "how do I do xyz?" is too broad to be a valid SO question (those need to be way more focused). My recommendation, assuming you know C++, is to read boost documentation and look online for examples on other C++ webservers that use boost

Boost has the boost::beast library to provide infrastructure for http(s) servers and clients. Haven't used the server components yet, but the clients work nice enough.

@PepijnKramer I think they just want to perform a http request. Don't need a server for that

@sehe Yeah it is all assumptions from here. It isn't a clear question at all

This should be a good start:
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/json.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace net   = boost::asio;
namespace beast = boost::beast;
namespace http  = beast::http;
namespace ssl   = net::ssl;
namespace json  = boost::json;
using tcp       = net::ip::tcp;

int main() {
    std::string const my_translator_key    = "YOUR_TRANSLATOR_KEY";
    std::string const my_resource_location = "westus";

    net::io_context ioc;
    tcp::resolver   resolver{ioc};
    auto            eps = resolver.resolve("api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com", "https");

    // Input and output languages are defined as parameters.
    std::string route           = "/translate?api-version=3.0&from=en&to=fr&to=zu";
    std::string textToTranslate = "I would really like to drive your car around the block a few times!";

    json::array body        = {{{"Text", textToTranslate}}};
    std::string requestBody = json::serialize(body);

    http::request<http::string_body> request;
    request.method(http::verb::post);
    request.target(route);
    request.set(http::field::content_type, "application/json");
    request.set(http::field::user_agent, "Beast");
    request.set(http::field::accept, "application/json");
    request.set(http::field::host, "api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com");
    request.set(http::field::authorization, "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: " + my_translator_key);
    request.set(http::field::authorization, "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region: " + my_resource_location);
    request.body() = requestBody;
    request.prepare_payload();

    tcp::socket s{ioc};
    net::connect(s, eps);

    ssl::context                          ctx{ssl::context::tlsv12_client};
    boost::beast::ssl_stream<tcp::socket> stream{std::move(s), ctx};
    stream.handshake(ssl::stream_base::client);

    http::write(stream, request);

    beast::flat_buffer                buffer;
    http::response<http::string_body> response;
    http::read(stream, buffer, response);

    std::cout << response.body() << std::endl;
}

Obviously I can't test it without endpoint key:

